# Python: Extracting all data from dictionary columns and put them into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a table that includes a column that includes a dictionary. In this dictionary, there is a key, and a list of dictionary values as follow:

| id | dict_vals |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | {'key_a':[{'a':1,'b':8,'c':7},{'a':14,'b':6,'c':8},{'a':9,'b':4,'c':9},...,{'a_t':67,'b_t':41,'c_t':6}]} |
| 345 | {'key_a':[{'a':5,'b':82,'c':72},{'a':4,'b':64,'c':81},{'a':5,'b':3,'c':6},...{'a_t':34,'b_t':23,'c_t':}]} |

Inside the nested dictionary list of values, all the keys are the same, expect for the last dictionary (e.g., a_t, b_t...). What I am trying to do, is to drop the last dictionary and convert everything else to column as the following:

| id | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 8 | 7 |
| 123 | 14 | 6 | 8 |
| 123 | 9 | 4 | 9 |
| 345 | 5 | 82 | 72 |
| 345 | 4 | 64 | 81 |
| 345 | 5 | 3 | 6 |

For the last dictionary (e.g., a_t, b_t), I have been able to separate them and convert them with the following code.

```
values = table.dict_vals.str.replace("'", '"').apply(json.loads).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
df.key_a = df.key_a.apply(lambda x: x[-1])
data_split = df["dict_vals"].apply(pd.Series)
```

Unfortunately, I am not sure how this method can be used to separate all the other dictionaries. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- For removing the last element in `list` you can return `list` with slicing like this `[:-1]`.
- You can extract dataframe from each `dict` and use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for merging all dataframes.
- You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for merging multiple `df`s.
- You can use [`pandas.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` and iterate each row and find the id from the original `df` and add to created `df`.

```
from functools import reduce
import ast

df_res = reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, how='outer'), 
                df.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(x['dict_vals'])['key_a'][:-1]).assign(id=df['id'][x.name]), axis=1)).set_index('id')


print(df_res)
```

Output:

```
      a   b   c
id             
123   1   8   7
123  14   6   8
123   9   4   9
345   5  82  72
345   4  64  81
345   5   3   6
```

Input DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : [123, 345],
    'dict_vals' : [{'key_a':[{'a':1,'b':8,'c':7},{'a':14,'b':6,'c':8},{'a':9,'b':4,'c':9}, {'a_t':67,'b_t':41,'c_t':6}]},
                   {'key_a':[{'a':5,'b':82,'c':72},{'a':4,'b':64,'c':81},{'a':5,'b':3,'c':6}, {'a_t':34,'b_t':23,'c_t':9}]}]
})
```

Comment: @l'mahdi thanks for your help. when I am trying your method, I get the "TypeError: string indices must be integers" for when you removed the last element. do you know how it can be fixed?

Comment: @Danny, try updated solution

Answer (score 0):

First add the data

```
import pandas as pd

keys = [
    {'key_a':[{'a':1,'b':8,'c':7},{'a':14,'b':6,'c':8},{'a':9,'b':4,'c':9},{'a_t':67,'b_t':41,'c_t':6}]},
    {'key_a':[{'a':5,'b':82,'c':72},{'a':4,'b':64,'c':81},{'a':5,'b':3,'c':6}, {'a_t':34,'b_t':23,'c_t':2}]}
]
```

Then some vars. There should be 1 id for each key that is in the keys list

```
ids = [123, 345]
id, a, b, c, = [], [], [], []
```

First for loop is loop for setting the ids of the dicts. Then we get dict from the list as a var **values** Then it's seperating the dict.

```
for idIndex in range(len(ids)):
    values = keys[idIndex]["key_a"]  # here is dict index of idIndex
    for i in range(len(values) - 1):  # here will drop last dict
        value = values[i]

        id.append(ids[idIndex])  # here your id
        a.append(value["a"])
        b.append(value["b"])
        c.append(value["c"])
```

Finaly create data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":id, "a": a, "b": b, "c": c})  # create data frame
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    id   a   b   c
0  123   1   8   7
1  123  14   6   8
2  123   9   4   9
3  345   5  82  72
4  345   4  64  81
5  345   5   3   6
```